# Hazelcast in ssl and Spymemcached client

Tags: ssl, hazelcast

Is it possible to have Hazelcast configured in SSL and to use hazelcast memcached enabled?

```
SSLConfig sslConfig = new SSLConfig();
sslConfig.setEnabled(true);
       sslConfig.setFactoryClassName("com.hazelcast.nio.ssl.BasicSSLContextFactory");
    sslConfig.getProperties().setProperty("keyStore", "path_to\\keystore.jks");
    sslConfig.getProperties().setProperty("keyStorePassword", "Password!");

    config.getNetworkConfig().setSSLConfig(sslConfig);


client = new MemcachedClient(AddrUtil.getAddresses("xxx.xxx.xx.xx:5701"));
client.get("key");
```

I believe we have to provide keystore info to the client as well. Is there a way to bind that.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: could you explain the reason to use Hazelcast with memcached?

Comment: we have a use case where we are going to replace memcache with hazlecast, so that the client implementation should not get changed!

Comment: please, share your Hazelcast config and spymemcached connection code

Comment: @VikGamov, updated the post. can u please have a look

Comment: could you point me to the `MemcachedClient` API to connect to `memcached` server via SSL? Is it supported by `MemcachedClient`?